# SQL - Select first n occurrences of each value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Let's say I have a table like so, only with thousands of records.

```
| Foo | Bar  | 
| 1   | A_1  | 
| 1   | A_2  | 
| 2   | B_1  | 
| 3   | B_1  | 
| 3   | B_2  | 
| 3   | B_1  | 
| 4   | B_3  | 
...
```

When I execute the code below, I obviously get each and every record where Bar begins with B.

```
SELECT Foo
FROM tableName
WHERE Bar LIKE 'B%'
```

I know using `GROUP BY` will get me the first 1 record of each, but I need more than just that. Using `SELECT TOP 100` will only net me the first 100 records, regardless of which "B" they are, and since there are far more than 100 B_1 values, that's all that I will get.

How can I only get the first *n* records for each unique B? For example, the first 100 occurrences of B_1, the first 100 of B_2, etc.

Comment: So....MySQL or SQL Server?, which version?

Comment: My bad, updating tags now...

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the [ROWNUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx) with [PARTION BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

```
SELECT Foo, Bar
FROM 
   (
     SELECT
         Foo,
         Bar,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BAR ORDER BY FOO) AS RowCount
     FROM
        tableName
    ) AS data
WHERE 
    data.RowCount <= 100
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a `PARTITION` on Bar:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  Foo, Bar,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Bar Order By Foo Asc) As Row_Number
    From    tableName
    Where   Bar Like 'B%'
)
Select  Foo, Bar
From    Cte
Where   Row_Number <= 100
```